# not displaying my json

Tags: php, arrays, json, mysqli

when i run this code nothing happens, i want to display it via json

```
  include 'connect.php';

   $con = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
   {
     echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }

     $query = "SELECT 
               firts_name,last_name,middle_name,path_to_photo_thumbnail FROM 
     CUSTOMERS";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

      $rows = array();
      if($result){
              while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
              {
                $rows[] = $r;
              }
       print(json_encode($rows));
        }
      mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

so that i can read in android studio

Comment: have you tried echo json_encode($rows); instead of print?

Comment: i already try dude, nothing happens same result. @Shahriat Hossain

Comment: @LawrenceCherone i already change dude thanks but the same problem nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Check whether your query has some error or not. Added `or die(mysqli_error($con));`

```
include 'connect.php';

   $con = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
   {
     echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }

     $query = "SELECT 
               first_name,last_name,middle_name,path_to_photo_thumbnail FROM 
     CUSTOMERS";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysqli_error($con));

      $rows = array();
      if($result){
              while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
              {
                $fetch = [
                    'first_name' => $r['first_name'],
                    'last_name' => $r['last_name'],
                    'middle_name' => $r['middle_name'],
                    'path_to_photo_thumbnail' => $r['path_to_photo_thumbnail'],
                ];
                $rows[] = $fetch;
              }

        }
      mysqli_close($con);
     echo json_encode($rows);
    ?>
```

Comment: same result return blank page no json data

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` to check if there are any error messages

Comment: can you just `echo 'TEST'` after each and every line to test, upto which line its coming

Comment: just to display the data from database via json format

Comment: @pat. Yeah i understand your question. There is some error. We need to debug that first

Comment: ill this one  $rows['test'] = $r; but it returns {"test":{"0":"Ernesto","first_name":"Ernesto","1":"Badong","last_name":"Badong","2":"","middle_name":"","3":"hulugan\/img\/placeholders-thumbnail\/e.jpg","path_to_photo_thumbnail":"hulugan\/img\/placeholders-thumbnail\/e.jpg"}}

Comment: How do you want the result then? Remove that `test` then

Comment: i want all the data in my table base on my query.. it only return single row data

Comment: i remove the 'test' no display

Comment: is there any possible solution sir?

Comment: @pat. There was a syntax error, modified my code again.Can you try again

Comment: still no data sir :(